# Derivation of Null Quantification in Logic?

Tags: logic

I was reading page 10-8 of this: https://faculty.washington.edu/smcohen/120/Chapter10.pdf
and I was wondering if the distributive qualities could be derived, e.g. $\forall x (P \lor Q(x)) \Leftrightarrow P \lor \forall x Q(x)$, and the equivalent one for $\exists , \land$.

Comment: In the *Lecture Notes* of the website there are (in the chapters following the one tou are referencing) the rules for quantifiers : $\forall$-intro, $\forall$-elim,... They must be used to prove the theroem above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following proof uses the rules of **Chapter 12: Methods of Proof for Quantifiers**.

I'll consider only the case :  $∀x(P∨Q(x)) \Rightarrow P∨∀xQ(x)$; the other one is similar.

(1)  $∀x(P∨Q(x))$ --- assumed

(2)  $P∨Q(a)$ --- from (1) by **universal instantiation**, or $\forall$-elim

Now we need some "propositional" transformation : we use the equivalence between $A \lor B$ and $\lnot A \Rightarrow B$

(3) $\lnot P \Rightarrow Q(a)$ --- from (2) by tautological equivalence

(4) $\lnot P$ --- assumed

(5) $Q(a)$ --- by $\Rightarrow$-elim (or *modus ponens*)

(6) $\forall xQ(x)$ --- by **universal introduction** (or $\forall$-intro) : the *constant* $a$ is not free in the assumptions

(7) $\lnot P \Rightarrow \forall xQ(x)$ --- from (4) and (6) by $\Rightarrow$-intro

(8) $P \lor \forall xQ(x)$ --- from (7) by tautological equivalence

> (9) $∀x(P∨Q(x)) \Rightarrow P \lor \forall xQ(x)$ --- from (1) by $\Rightarrow$-intro.

---

*Note*

If we don't want to use the *tautological equivalence* in steps (3) and (8), we can use a "proof by cases".

From step :

(2) $P \lor Q(a)$

(3) $P$ --- assumed for $\lor$-elim

(4) $P \lor \forall x Q(x)$ --- from (3) by $\lor$-intro

(5) $Q(a)$ --- assumed for $\lor$-elim

(6) $\forall xQ(x)$ --- by **universal introduction** (or $\forall$-intro) : the *constant* $a$ is not free in the assumptions

(7) $P \lor \forall x Q(x)$ --- from (6) by $\lor$-intro

(8) $P \lor \forall x Q(x)$ --- from (2), (4) and (7) by $\lor$-elim, "discharging" the temporary assumptions (3) and (5).

Theorem follows as above, by $\Rightarrow$-intro.

---

*Added*

The other "direction" is easier.

From the assumption : $P \lor \forall x Q(x)$, we derive from both $P$ and $\forall xQ(x)$ separately : $P \lor Q(a)$ [in one case by $\lor$-intro; in the other case by $\forall$-elim followed by $\lor$-intro].

Then we apply again proof by cases ($\lor$-elim) to conclude from : $P \lor \forall x Q(x)$ to : $P \lor Q(a)$.

Finally we apply $\forall$-intro to derive : $\forall x(P \lor Q(x))$ followed by a final $\Rightarrow$-intro.

---

*Comment*

Please note that, in general : $\forall xP(x) \lor \forall xQ(x) \vdash \forall x(P(x) \lor Q(x))$, but **not** vice versa, i.e. :

> > $\forall x(P(x) \lor Q(x)) \nvdash \forall xP(x) \lor \forall xQ(x)$.

In other words, the above proof does not works if $x$ is *free* in $P$.

Why so ?

Because (consider the first proof above) in step (6) we have to apply $\forall$-intro to $Q(a)$ to get $\forall xQ(x)$.

If $x$ is *free* in $P$ [and this is so if we try to apply the proof to the assumption $\forall x(P(x) \lor Q(x))$, because in step (2) we have instantiated it to $P(a) \lor Q(a)$], if we try to apply $\forall$-intro we have to violate the proviso that the constant $a$ must not be *free* in the assumptions, and at that step of the proof we still have an "undischarged" assumption containing $a$ : exactly $P(a)$.

Comment: Why can you assume $\neg P$ in step 4?

Comment: @Anthony - We can assume whatever we need, provided that we "discharge" it before the end of the proof, if - as in this case - we are proving a *logical theorem*, i.e. a *valid* formula which does not depend on assumptions.

Comment: But don't you need to consider the situation where P is true as well? Or is it because the only thing you're really interested in with an implication is what happens when the antecedent is true?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't seem like the notes you're reading define any deductive system for FOL at all, and you can't derive *anything* before you have a deductive system to do it in.

However, once you *have* a deductive system for FOL (of which there are several to choose among), you will be able to derive these laws in it. Otherwise the system you have is not FOL!

Comment: Oof. I'm not sure what deductive system I *normally* use, I just was trying to figure out why Null Quantification makes sense.

Comment: @Anthony: If you're just trying to gain an intuitive understanding of why the rules hold, I think that's easier by thinking about the _semantics_ rather than about derivations of them. To wit, in each possible world, $P$ is either true or false. So, depending on which of those is the case, the content of the rule is either $$\forall x({\sf True}\lor \cdots)\Leftrightarrow {\sf True}\lor \cdots$$ or $$\forall x(Q(x))\Leftrightarrow \forall x\,Q(x)$$ each of which is clearly always true.

Comment: I suppose I did want more than intuition though- derivations are always nice. There are a few other cases to consider, no?

Comment: @Anthony: The semantics of FOL can (and should) be formalized; it is not just intuitive handwaving. And I don't see which other cases there would be to consider. (The rules are only valid if $P$ does not contain $x$ free, and therefore in any given interpretation $P$ has the same truth value no matter which value $x$ is considered to have).